# How to count the number of rows and insert if not or update in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have counted the total number of rows in Magento. But, i have to set a condition that if no records found need to insert if it is there have to update. how to check this?

```
public function execute(){

      $params = (array)$this->getRequest()->getPost();  


     $collection_count = $this->_doccountfactory->create()->getCollection()->count();
     echo $collection_count;

     if($collection_count>1){

     }
}
```

Comment: have you post data with primary key (unique id)? for eg. your table primary key entity_id

Comment: i have post dat with unique id

Answer (score 1):

You can load your model with your **primary key**.

If you get the id, load your model with that id and then set data otherwise set the data directly.

See the following demo

```
<?php

private $customModel;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Vendor\Module\Magento\ModuleFactory $customModel
)  {
    ....
    $this->customModel = $customModel;
}

public function execute()
{
    $model = $this->customModel->create();

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();  
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
    }

    $model->setData($data);
    $model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();  
$doccountModel = $this->_doccountfactory->create();
if($id) {
   $doccountModel = $doccountModel->load($id);
}
$doccountModel->setData($postData);
$doccountModel->save();
```